# correct return of sed and renaming

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have several files named with different lenght, but have a pattern i can find to used SED.
I want to remove a determined set of characters in the middle of it so i can rename them, but i am failing miserably at some points...
the example file is:

[Matheus]_203-34510033_20220217111125(237).wav

the name in the begging changes, as well as the value inside the parentheses, that is incremented on each file and soon will be bigger than 3 digits.
I need to remove the 6 digits before the parenthesis, and my regex can find them correctly:

```
s/.*_203.*_202\d{5}\K.+?(?=\()//
```

[regex exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx1Rf.png)

I am using the following script so i can rename the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *.wav; do
  newFilename=$(sed -E 's/.*_203.*_202\d{5}\K.+?(?=\()//' <<< "$filename")
  mv "$filename" "$newFilename"
done
```

when i run the script, i receive the output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, character 46: Invalid Preceding regular expression.
```

What is wrong with my sed?

---

EDIT:

Solution given by The Fourth Bird worked:
newFilename=$(sed -E 's/(_203.*_202[0-9]{5})[0-9]+(()/\1\2/' <<< "$filename")

Comment: PCRE patterns are not supported in `sed`, it only supports POSIX regex flavors.

Comment: `newFilename=$(sed -E 's/(_203.*_202[0-9]{5})[0-9]+(\()/\1\2/' <<< "$filename")`

Comment: please update the question to include the expected result, ie, the expected value in `newfilename`

Comment: Perhaps you should use the utility `rename` which will accept your substitution command as is i.e. `rename -n -v 's/.*_203.*_202\d{5}\K.+?(?=\()//' *.wav`, when happy with the result, remove the `-n` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the pattern between parenthesis, the (?=...) syntax is not supported.
Your pattern will probably become

```
s/.*_203.*_202[0-9]{5}.+?\(([^\)]+)\)/\1/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Perl based `rename` command:

```sh
$ rename -n 's/.*_203.*_202\d{5}\K.+?(?=\()//' *.wav
rename([Matheus]_203-34510033_20220217111125(237).wav, [Matheus]_203-34510033_20220217(237).wav)
```

`-n` option is for dry run, remove it for actual renaming. Also, you don't need the `.*` at the start of the regexp.

> I need to remove the 6 digits before the parenthesis

```sh
rename -n 's/\d{6}(?=\()//' *.wav
```

---

If you don't have the command installed, check your distribution's repository or you can install it from [metacpan: File::Rename](https://metacpan.org/dist/File-Rename/view/rename.PL).